# ANTLRWorks - How to work with Python 2.5 grammar

Tags: python, antlr, antlrworks

I need to find ANTLR grammar for Python (I found this, on antlr site http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1200715779785/Python.g)
Then i need to test grammar and to add AST.
I planned to do this in ANTLRWorks, but I can't figure it out. In this grammar says that i need additional file PythonTokenStream.java and I found that too but I don't know how to set it up.
My question is:

- How to test python code examples with this grammar in ANTLRWorks (I did this by opening grammar with ANTLRWorks , Generate>Generate Code, Run>Debug)?
- How to use this additional PythonTokenStream.java file?

I'm totaly new with ANTLR so every help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A useful example use of ANTLR for python is the parser used in the jython library: https://bitbucket.org/jython/jython.  It makes use of the same grammar file.  Check out the repository and look in the src/org/python/antlr directory.  You should run the build script (`cd` into the root directory and run `ant`) and then look in `build/gensrc`.  ANTLR works by generating a bunch of source files into this directory using the grammar file.  You can look at `build.xml` to get a sense of the process.

Comment: I set enviroment in Eclipse and began rewriting grammar file to implement all functions in .g file (because i work on project which shouldnt use additional file). But these links you suggested have very useful information.